# How to refer same mongo store from one node app to other app using connect-mongodb-session package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, connect-mongo

I have two node app projects, where one is for the login authentication server (server_app.js) and another one is dashboard node project (app_dashboard.js). I'm storing sessions in mongodb store collection named sessions.

server_app.js

```
const mongoDbStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const uuidv4 = require('uuid').v4;
const store = new mongoDbStore({
    uri: MONGODB_URI,
    collection: 'sessions'
});
app.use(session({
    secret: uuidv4(),
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: 'localhost',
    },
    store: store,
    name: 'sid',

}))
```

Now I'm forwarding session_id to another app after successful login in cookies and I want to refer the same MongoDB store in my session of app_dashboard.js, How do I make it work to refer same mongo store used in server_app.js to validate my sessions?

app_dashboard.js

```
app.use(session({
    secret: uuidv4(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // name: 'sessionid',
    // store: store
}))
```

Comment: If you just use the same settings for the `store` and the `session`, does it work? You'll need to have the same `secret` for both, so generate a cryptographically secure random string for that and pass it into both via environment variables (`process.env`).

Comment: Thanks this worked, I applied the same secret keys for both app sessions settings and its referring to the same mongo store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same options for the `store` and `session` on both. You'll need to have the same `secret` for both, so generate a cryptographically secure random string for that and pass it into both via environment variables (`process.env`).